# PowerShell Remoting Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: serialization, powershell

Are the routines for serializing and deserializing objects from PowerShell (as performed by PowerShell Remoting) available?

I'd like to avoid having to write the objects to disk (with Export-CliXML) and reading it back in with (Import-CliXML).

Basically, I want to get the property bags that the deserialization creates so that I can add them to an AppFabric object cache.  Otherwise, AppFabric tries to use .NET serialization, which fails for a number of the standard object types.

Perhaps through the $host or $executioncontext variables?

Comment: Have you read [Object Serialization Directives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/05/01/object-serialization-directives.aspx) and [How objects are sent to and from remote sessions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions.aspx) from Jeffrey Snover. I'am not sure that it gives you the solution, but perhaps a clue.

Comment: Thanks @JPBlanc.  I've read those posts and while they tell me what is going on, I am hoping to not have to re-invent the wheel on implementing it..

Comment: @Steve, Can you be a little more specific about what you are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How many different types of objects would you be serializing? If they are your own objects, you can throw attributes on to your class and its properties to tell the serialization process how to serialize it - check out the iserializable interface

Comment: I'm looking to do just about anything I deal with in the course of my day working with PowerShell. I'm comfortable customizing the serialization of my classes, but the PowerShell system does a nice job in serializing with Export-CliXML and remoting.  I'd like to leverage that if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have published the PowerShell Remoting Specification which would give you the spec, but the source code they used to implement it is not public at this time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357801(PROT.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see what you're asking, you're looking for a ConvertTo-CliXml similar to how ConvertTo-Csv works in place of Export-Csv.  At first glance it sounds like you're trying to avoid CliXml entirely.

In that case, there's one on PoshCode: [ConvertTo-CliXml](http://poshcode.org/4050) [ConvertFrom-CliXml](http://poshcode.org/4051)

Here's a verbatim copy to give you an idea (I haven't checked this for correctness):

```
function ConvertTo-CliXml {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [PSObject[]]$InputObject
    )
    begin {
        $type = [PSObject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.Serializer')
        $ctor = $type.GetConstructor('instance,nonpublic', $null, @([System.Xml.XmlWriter]), $null)
        $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
        $xw = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter $sw
        $serializer = $ctor.Invoke($xw)
        $method = $type.GetMethod('Serialize', 'nonpublic,instance', $null, [type[]]@([object]), $null)
        $done = $type.GetMethod('Done', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'nonpublic,instance')
    }
    process {
        try {
            [void]$method.Invoke($serializer, $InputObject)
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Could not serialize $($InputObject.GetType()): $_"
        }
    }
    end {    
        [void]$done.Invoke($serializer, @())
        $sw.ToString()
        $xw.Close()
        $sw.Dispose()
    }
}
```