# how to get FileInfo from PSObject returned by Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to get some file infos from a folder in a remote server with Invoke-Command

```
$files =  Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $serversi   -ScriptBlock {$remoteFiles= Get-ChildItem -Path  $using:path
        Write-Host $remoteFiles.getType();
         return $remoteFiles;
    } ;
   

        Write-Host $files.getType();
```

the remote object is System.IO.FileInfo
but it is returned as System.Management.Automation.PSObject

Can I get FileInfo or FileInfo array from PSObject?
Whatever I tried didn't work.

Comment: You need to read this post about Serialization. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621063/powershell-remoting-serialization-and-deserialization

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate your error but this works and returns file objects:

```
$Path = "C:\"
$files =  Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $Path -ComputerName $serversi -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Args[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. Some pointers:

- Always use full variable names that mean something. If the names are already known in PowerShell use those (`$serversi` becomse `$computerName`)
- Use `Write-Verbose` instead of `Write-Host`. It will show you the progress you want to see. `Write-Host` serves a different purpose, displaying messages in the terminal, and will pollute the pipeline or the information you expect.
- Try to splat your arguments, it makes it easier on the eyes `@{paramName = paramValue}`
- Know that everything is returned by default. So no need to use the `Return` keyword. It is only useful when you want to leave a function early for example.

```
$invokeParams = @{
    Credential   = $credentials 
    ComputerName = $computerName
}

$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' # hide Write-Verbose messages
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue' # show Write-Verbose messages

$files = Invoke-Command @invokeParams -ScriptBlock {
    # if you only want files use the '-File' switch
    Get-ChildItem -Path  $using:path -File 

    <# # another way
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Path  $using:path
    $result # no need for the 'Return' as everything is returned by default 
    #>

    # NEVER use Write-Host as it is returned and will confuse you
}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # use Write-Verbose to show you details that will not pollute the pipeline
    Write-Verbose "File '$($file.FullName)' is of type $($files.getType())"    
}
```